# Checkbox acting like radio button | Using icheck.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, icheck

I have created three checkboxes as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
```

I want these checkboxes to act like radio buttons and using the following jQuery, I am nearly achieving this. I am also using the icheck.js library, so I am doing the jQuery code like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('ifChanged', function() {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).iCheck('uncheck');
});
```

However this is only working with the first change, as soon as I click the third time it doesn't work any longer. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why not just style the radio button as check boxes?

Comment: @AdamAzad Cause I want to enable the user to be able to unselect everything, and I cannot make a radio button de-selectable

Comment: Can you share your code with jsfiddle?

Comment: @oguzhancerit I cannot manage to replicate exactly what I am getting: https://jsfiddle.net/ro895g71/1/

Answer (score 0):

I can not use Icheck plugin but I did with standart checkbox.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
     $(this).prop('checked',true);
   }
   else {
     $(this).prop('checked',true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
```

Comment: The problem is that when using icheck, the prop does not work as the checkbox is worked totally different. Is it possible you try it with icheck ?

Comment: @MarjinooBajello I am trying now, wait a minute.

Comment: @MarjinooBajello I am sorry bro, I can't use this plugin. I download from github, loaded all scripts but it is not working :). I recommend you change it with new checkbox plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Base on a previous answer, there's no reason for the if statement inside.. this solution will remove all checked, then check the appropriate selection right after.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
<input type="checkbox" name="upgrade">
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
  $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

https://jsbin.com/qeqemuqaci/edit?html,js,output